# converting useffect into class component

Tags: react-native

```
    const displayNameRef = useRef('');
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const loginMethod = await AsyncStorage.getItem('login-method');
    if (loginMethod === 'google') {
      displayNameRef.current = await AsyncStorage.getItem('google-user-name');

      setState((s) => s + 1);
    } else {
      displayNameRef.current = 'Randomly_generated';
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

this is my useffect, here i  getitem(display name )from async storage but i want to convert all the hooks into class component

```
 <Header
        title={('hi', displayNameRef.current)}
        setSelectedTab={this.setSelectedTab}
        selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}
        openDrawerPanel={this.openDrawerPanel}
      />
```

so here i want to display `displayNameRef.current` inside of header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn your hooks into class component, try to process à below:

```
class SomeCalss extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            s: 0
        }
        this.displayNameRef = React.createRef();
      }

    
    async componentDidMount() {
        
        const loginMethod = await AsyncStorage.getItem('login-method');

        if (loginMethod === 'google') {

            displayNameRef.current = await AsyncStorage.getItem('google-user-name');
            this.setState({s: this.state.s + 1});

        } else {
            displayNameRef.current = 'Randomly_generated';
        }
    }
    
    render() {

        return  <Header
                    title={('hi', this.displayNameRef.current)}
                    setSelectedTab={this.setSelectedTab}
                    selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    openDrawerPanel={this.openDrawerPanel}
                />
    }
}
```

But you have to be aware that `displayNameRef.current = 'Randomly_generated';` doesn't trigger re-render